# Build C++ RTMAPS package on Ubuntu 16.04 & Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, compilation, cross-compiling

- I'm working on a C++ project that should support Ubuntu 18 & Ubuntu 16.
- I'm actually working on QT (but I'm not sure this is useful information): QT 5.13.2 GCC 64bit
- With a C++ compiler: GCC(C++, x86 64bit in /usr/bin)
- This project uses a library that I acquired when installing the RTMAPS SDK.

**So** when I compile it and use it in a PC with Ubuntu 18.04 it works fine. When I try using it in a PC with Ubuntu 16.04 I get the error:

**Error: Unable to load package */path/*: it was built for another operating system (Ubuntu 18.4)**

- I have compiled this same project in a Ubuntu 16.04 PC and it runs in the that PC.

**Questions:**

- Is there a way to compile on Ubuntu 18.04 targeting 16.04? (or in general different versions?)
- If the library is *also* a problem, can I just copy paste one generated in Ubuntu 16.04?

  - Can I have RTMAPS's libraries for both OSs in the smae environement?

Comment: Are both the PC's running same architecture processor?

Comment: Yes! Same architecture @yadhu

Comment: It seems like the problem is due to the different paths for libraries in 18.04 and 16.04. Maybe you can try shipping your application together with required libraries.

Comment: So many questions... You are using Qt 5.13 in a distribution that only ship Qt 5.9, so are you using a Qt installer instead of the Qt libraries provided by the distribution?

Comment: Another question: are you packaging your application as a .deb package, or .snap, or .AppImage, or a simple directory, maybe a compressed tarball? What is your preference and or requirement? And about your error message: this comes when you install your package, or when you run the application?

Comment: @Pedro I just used the installer that you find in QT's web site. On the other hand, I'm generating a .pck. that's a package that can be read by RTMAPS, which is basically a library with "block coding" functions

Comment: The error appears when registering the package into a "diagram". In other words I don't get to the point where I can run it.

Comment: So this question seems to be more related to the "RTMPAS SDK" (you probably want to review the spelling of that), than to any other tag of your question. I don't know that ".pck" format, but maybe if you attach the right tags to your question someone else may be able to answer it.